# Join Solution for offset columns

Tags: t-sql, join

I would like to select data from two columns, both of similar length(@fetch) but at a certain offset in the same table.

However off the bat I am running into syntax errors.I would prefer a join solution for this. Thanks.

```
SELECT c.[Close],h.[High]
FROM 
    (
    SELECT [Close],[CityID],[Time]
    FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperature]
    WHERE [Time]<@time
    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY
    ) AS c

JOIN 
    (
    SELECT [High],[CityID],[Time]
    FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperature]
    WHERE [Time]<@time
    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
    OFFSET (@offset) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY
    )  AS h

ON c.[CityID]=h.[CityID] AND  c.[Time]=h.[Time]

WHERE c.[CityID]=@name AND h.[CityID]=@name;
```

EDIT:
This is now returning more than expected results with repetitions in both columns

EDIT:
This now returns columns that are in same row without offset because I required primary keys to match! There has to be an offset and the problem is this table contains data for more than two cities so you cannot use ROW_NUMBER()!

Here is my table schema:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Temperature](
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CityID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [High] [real] NULL,
    [Close] [real] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_time_cityid] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Time] ASC,
    [CityID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Temperature]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Temperature_Cities] FOREIGN KEY([CityID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Cities] ([CityID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Temperature] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Temperature_Cities]
GO
```

Comment: `OFFSET O ROWS` should be `OFFSET 0 ROWS`.  Beyond that, you should post your error message.

Comment: Thanks. After placing the 0, error messages are:                               Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near '@fetch'.

Comment: Also added ONLY at end of FETCH NEXT

Comment: Errors now are invalid column name CityID for c.[CityID] and h.[CityID]

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind you *can* edit your question to correct your query.

In addition to `OFFSET 0 ROWS` and `FETCH NEXT (...) ROWS ONLY` issues, you need to use `SELECT [CityID],[Close]` and `SELECT [CityID],[High]` in your subqueries respectively.  The only fields from a subquery that are available outside the subquery are those you explicitly specify.  That includes JOIN conditions.

Regarding your comment that you're getting the number of rows you expect squared, you've probably got an implicit cross join that's creating a Cartesian product.  You need to join your tables using the fields in the primary key of `dbo.temperature`.  Try adding some sample data to your question and possibly the table schema.